# Is it possible to use vaadin-grid in a Polymer 2 application?

Tags: polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

In this page:
https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-core-elements
I see that vaadin-grid should be supported in a Polymer 2 application.
I tried in every way to make this (vaadin) example work:

```
    <vaadin-grid items='[{"name": "John", "surname": "Lennon", "role": "singer"}, {"name": "Ringo", "surname": "Starr", "role": "drums"}]'>
        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Name</template>
            <template>[[item.name]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>
        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Surname</template>
            <template>[[item.surname]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>
        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Role</template>
            <template>[[item.role]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>
    </vaadin-grid>
```

But I get every sort of errors inside the vaadin source code...
Has anyone ever tried to use it in a Polymer 2 app?
Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Vaadin-grid should work with 2.0. can you add additional details for the errors you are getting and what you have done so far while debugging?

Comment: I received a clarification that the current version (2.0.x) of the grid component cannot work on Polymer 2 applications, I have to use 3.0.alpha.something... It was not clear, I will give a look during the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

To use vaadin-grid in Polymer 2.x download vaadin-grid v3.0.0-alpha2. You can download it using following command:
`bower install --save vaadin/vaadin-grid@v3.0.0-alpha2`
Vaadin-grid version 2.x doesn't support Polymer 2.x.
[Reference](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/885).

Comment: ...it's what I had already said in the comments... :-) and it appears working, indeed! Thank you very much, anyway!!!